# Keep Codename One updated

Tags: codenameone

I didn't understand if to keep Codename One up to date, so that the local code matches the one on the build servers, I always have to manually remind myself to right click on the project, then on "Run Maven" -> "Update Codename One" (in Netbeans) or if there is an automatic update. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to fix:

```xml
    <cn1.version>LATEST</cn1.version>
```

Setting this to `LATEST` will make sure you're always using the current version of Codename One. This should be the default when downloading from start.codenameone.com but wasn't the default until recently.

The plugin version needs to be updated manually:

```xml
    <cn1.plugin.version>7.0.29</cn1.plugin.version>
```

Once a week you can see a commit like this: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/48f0452bbb92f06653155ec3e8536e6b5e3bdcb6 which tells you the latest version (currently 7.0.29).

This version can't be automated and should be modified more "carefully" since the plugin might break compatibility and require additional changes. E.g the current version moved some files from the root to make the project look cleaner.

Comment: Thanks Shai, but I'm a little confused. In your answer you refer to a couple of manual changes to the `pom.xml` (which in my case currently contains `<cn1.plugin.version>7.0.29</cn1.plugin.version><cn1.version>7.0.29</cn1.version>`), but you make no mention of the "cn1:update" goal contained in `nbactions.xml` and used by me so far via "Run Maven" -> "Update Codename One". Could you explain the difference between the two approaches?

Comment: I think that just updates the related tools, not the libraries. Not sure I'll check.

Comment: I just checked. Setting `<cn1.version>LATEST</cn1.version>` and then running  "Run Maven" -> "Update Codename One" produces the following log: `Existing cn1.version=LATEST Existing cn1.plugin.version=7.0.29 Attempting to update project to version 7.0.29 Setting cn1.version=7.0.29 cn1.plugin.version already up to date. Not changing.` and then `<cn1.version>LATEST</cn1.version>` is changed in `<cn1.version>7.0.29</cn1.version>`. So this Maven goal updates plugin and cn1 version to the lastest ones, but it doesn't accept of use of the word `LATEST`, replacing it with an explicit version number.

Comment: Update is probably a mistake. Maven should self update.